# Magento 2 Migration "Invalid config filename"

Tags: magento2, migration

so I'm attempting to run a migration from Magento 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.2.5

I've installed the Migration Tool, made all the necessary changes to the config.xml file, and have tried to start the process but I get..

```
Migration\Exception]
  Invalid config filename: /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource- 
to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
```

This is what I'm attempting to run...

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset /vendor/magento/data-migration- 
tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
```

I've double checked and validated the config.xml and the connected config.xsd files and it flags up an error with the .xsd file...

```
InvalidRegex: Pattern value '[-/A-Za-z0-9\._]+\.(xml|dist)' is not a valid 
regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character 
range. Write
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do here.  Others make mention of this but I can't find a specific solution.  I've never actually edited the .xsd file, so find this issue puzzling.

HEre is my config file

```
<steps mode="settings">
    <step title="Settings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
    </step>
    <step title="Stores Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Data Integrity Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
    </step>
    <step title="EAV Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Ratings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Tier Price Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="PostProcessing Step">
        <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
    </step>
</steps>
<steps mode="delta">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<source>
    <database host="localhost" name="x" user="x" password="x" />
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="x" user="x" password="x"/>
</destination>
<options>
    <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/map.xml</map_file>
    <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
    <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
    <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
    <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
    <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
    <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
    <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
    <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
    <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>
    <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
    <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
    <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
    <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml</class_map>
    <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
    <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file>
    <!--
    In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
    -->
    <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
    <!--
    Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
    NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
    and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
     -->
    <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
    <source_prefix>mg_</source_prefix>
    <dest_prefix></dest_prefix>
    <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
    <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
    <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
    <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
    <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
    <edition_number>1.9.2.4</edition_number>
    <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
    <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
    <crypt_key>xrjpunf3198ovo8gulih8yctkl53ibr8</crypt_key>
</options>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your config.xml file

> etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/map.xml

```
    <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>

    <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>

    <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>

    <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml</log_map_file>

    <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>

    <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml</settings_map_file>

    <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>

    <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>

    <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>

    <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>

    <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>

    <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml</class_map>

    <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>

    <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file> 

    <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>

    <!--
    In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
    -->
    <bulk_size>100</bulk_size>
    <!--
    Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
    NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
    and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
     -->
    <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
    <source_prefix></source_prefix>
    <dest_prefix></dest_prefix>
    <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
    <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
    <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
    <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
    <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
    <edition_number>1.9.2.4</edition_number>
    <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
    <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
    <crypt_key>f5b73daae42423c828cd62e75c84662b</crypt_key>
</options
```

Make all extension with .xml and remove .xml.dst
All file exists here
\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\opensource-to-opensource

Comment: Thanks - yes I had done all that.  I didn't remove the .dist files though.  I just copied and renamed.

Comment: Have you added source and destination and also <source_prefix></source_prefix>
        <dest_prefix></dest_prefix>  in your config.xml file?

Comment: In your code why below code repeated?
1)
   <source_prefix>mg_</source_prefix>
<dest_prefix></dest_prefix>
<crypt_key>x</crypt_key>

2)
<source_prefix />
    <dest_prefix />
<crypt_key />

Comment: Thanks, but that makes no difference.  The error remains.

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/503
May this can help you

Comment: I had seen that.  No help unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please share your config.xml and map.xml and system.xml file

Comment: I haven't edited the map.xml.  It is also 2000 lines long, so would be difficult to share here. I will update my first post to include the full config.xml

Comment: hi @RutveeSojitra, I am getting below error, Invalid map filename: vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist, can you help me please

Comment: @jafarpinjar just remove .dist extension from file and vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, I have fixed that error n migrated data successfully, Now i want to migrate only latest sales orders n customers. Is that can be done? can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the file structure in my original php request.

I was running from within my public_html folder (cd public_html), jumping up a level seemed to have made the difference.

php public_html/bin/magento migrate:settings --reset public_html/vendor/magento/data-migration- 
tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml

All fixed.